# jQuery if then slideshow issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, controls, slideshow

I've got a slideshow that's manually controlled with previous and next buttons. It works fine, but using `insertBefore` and `insertAfter` feels sloppy, so I'd like to explore some other methods. Instead, I'm thinking "if this is the last image, go back to the first + the opposite for going backwards.

Here's my code, but I'm not getting the desired result when it hits the last image (where it should fade in the first and start all over.

Syntaxual? `if (slide == $('.z:last'))` looks fishy to me.

Test site: http://brantley.dhut.ch/

Thanks!

Here's my JavaScript:

```
        $('#next').click(function() {
            var slide = $('.z:visible'),
                next  = $('.z:visible').next();

            slide.fadeOut(400, function() {
                slide.removeClass('active');
                if (slide == $('.z:last')) {
                    $('.z:first').addClass('active');
                    bromance();
                    $('.z:first').fadeIn(400);
                } else {
                    next.addClass('active');
                    bromance();
                    next.fadeIn(400);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing?

Comment: @RoccoC5 - when it gets to the end (when slide IS .z:last), it doesn't fade in the first and all that junk. So I assume its some little syntax deal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (slide[0] == $('.z:last')[0]) { ...
```

jQuery doesn't return a reference to a DOM element directly, it returns an object that is array-like, where each array element is a DOM element matching the selector you used. This means comparing the results from two selectors is comparing two different array-like objects which isn't ever going to match even if they contain the same elements. Compare the first element in each array instead (because in your case you're expecting only one element anyway).

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `slide = $('.active')` and try `:first-child` instead of `:first`

Answer (score 0):

I would compare element ids for equality.

Change `if (slide == $('.z:last'))` to `if (slide.attr('id') === $('.z:last').attr('id'))`.

Or, you can test to see if the last slide is visible like so:

```
if ($('.z:last:visible')) {
    // last slide is visible
}
```

Comment: This won't work, because the things you're comparing aren't elements, they're jQuery objects. See my answer...

Comment: @nnnnnn - You are right...I edited my post to get the id via the `attr()` function.

Answer (score 0):

> next  = $('.z:visible').next();

check the below condition and specify the next image accordingly.

```
if($('.z:last')){
   next = $(".z:first")
}
else{
   next  = $('.z:visible').next();
}
```